# How to retrieve amazon ses email with message id

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have the message id, how can I use it to get the email from Amazon ses? I am using php and I am already receiving the notifications from my lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I stored the email to amazon s3 using s3 as an option when email is received. S3 stores the file with the same id.
I retrieved and parsed the email contents using [enter link description here](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNS instead of Lambda function, and in the SNS there is the email body and all the needed information